# RoR Empty Cart/Delete line_Items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I'm still pretty new to RoR and have run into a problem I can't seem to solve. I've already built the functions to add new products to the database and allow a user to add individual items to their cart, my delete method just gives me an error saying it can't find the delete method in the carts_controller. Any help would be appreciated.

\app\views\cart\show.html.erb

```
<%= button_to 'Empty Cart', @cart, method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: 'are you sure?'} %>
```

\app\controllers\carts_controller.rb

```
def destroy
 @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
 session[:cart_id] = nil
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to store_url,
     notice: 'Your cart is empty' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
def set_cart
  @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
end
```

Error Message Given

> Unknown Action
>   The action 'destroy' could not be found for CartsController

\config\routes.rb

```
Depot::Application.routes.draw do

root 'store#index', as: 'store'
resources :line_items
resources :carts
get "store/index"
resources :products

end
```

Comment: Show your routes - most likely you don't link to the action there. (Classic Rails would magically scrape every action from a controller. This scheme is since discarded due to the incredible mayhem it caused.)

Comment: Updated to show my routes.rb file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what is currently set in your `@cart` variable, can you put out an inspect for that?

Otherwise, you can also try something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Empty Cart', cart_path(@cart), method: :delete, confirm: 'are you sure?' %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but that still produces the same error, "The action 'destroy' could not be found for CartsController". I have updated my destroy method to include the private set_cart method if thats what you meant by "depends on what is set in the cart instance variable, which is: @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])

Comment: Just making sure that the destroy method is not under private or protected is it? The routing seems to be right

Comment: Thank you derekyau as it turns out I did have another private method (def invalid_cart) above the destroy method. After moving it to the very bottom of the controller everything is working fine.